# MS Word 2010 template text form field condition

Tags: sql, vba, ms-word

we got a word template that gets a mail feed from SQL. 
It has three text form field :

txtFirstname
txtLastname
txtcompany

If the feed has no firstname and lastname i.e blank and has a company name then
the company name needs to be moved to the txtFirstname field. hence moved to the left. Aligned to the left.

Text form field control is in Developer\legacy forms\text from field

I guess need code to run macro on exit in the txtcompany field...

Answer (score 0):

When they are blank they should just have a space inside the container, so they should automaticaly move to the left if the others are blank. Are there any styling applied to them? Also make sure they are not in a table, as it wont move.

Hope this helped - Jim

Comment: Text form field control is in Developer\legacy forms\text from field. They dont move automaticaly to the left.

Comment: @rosebud Not to sure then, sorry :/